# Changing line width by classification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, style, classification

I am using QGIS 2.18.18

I have a map of rivers and I want to style them based on their width. I have width as an attribute of the rivers layer.

Just as we can style colors by category or graduated styling, I want to do the same with width. 
Currently I use an expression editor for data driven override (circled in the picture) after which I have to manually classify everything. 
If classification could be done by  quantiles, jenks or other breaks automatically, then it would be easier for me to see which classification has what effect on my map. As I said, that is possible with color, but I cannot figure out how to do it with width

If there is a way to do it without code that would be great, as I haven't learnt that yet. If there isn't, then I'll implement it once I learn code.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use graduted stylings for color and also size when using point or line features. In case of lines the size is used to classify the width. There you find also the options for natural breaks and other classifications.

[image]

Comment: Haha thanks. I totally skipped over it while using graduated

Comment: @Matte I was wondering why I am not able to see the graduated colors still.

Comment: Can you check if your datatype is numeric? Won´t work with text.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Symbology, Single Symbol, Simple Line and click to **Edit**:

[image: Edit line stroke width]

Then open the option 'Fields and values' and refer to the attribute name containing the pen widths.
[image: Pen widths based on attribute data, Natural Earth rivers data set]