# Line width and labels based on blended values of features sharing same geometry in QGIS

Tags: labeling, line, geometry, qgis-2, overlapping-features

I want to appropriate line segments that share the same geometry with a particular line width and labels based on the aggregated values of one field `"GIS@BUS_5_Min"`.

My attribute table and polyline objects look as following, see image below.

[image: Example]

`"BUSLINIE"` means a bus line, `"Overlap"` means if the line has overlaps, i.e. it's geometry repeats.

Values of the field `"GIS@BUS_5_Min"` for these three objects has to be aggregated as one value and represented as a label `sum("GIS@BUS_5_Min")`.

And the width of this line (selected in yellow) will be `sum("GIS@BUS_5_Min")/100 = 19.10/100 = 0.1910`

How can I achieve such output?

I assume it is possible with `Layer Properties > Width > Data defined override > Edit...`, but I do not know how to check the same geometry and how to sum the values of certain features with `CASE WHEN condition THEN result END` conditional function?

The "Dissolve" function does not work in my case because I do not have any key-fields.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Line width transition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273563/qgis-line-width-transition)
- [Blend differing line thicknesses in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252680/blend-differing-line-thicknesses-in-qgis)
- [Changing line width by classification in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280431/changing-line-width-by-classification-in-qgis)
- [How to sum up values of overlapping polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/how-to-sum-up-values-of-overlapping-polygons-in-qgis)
- [Merging attribute and geometric features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233489/merging-attribute-and-geometric-features-in-qgis)

Comment: You could add a field and, for all overlapping segments, choose a parent segment who could become the key to aggregate with. From there you could use the information from this [blog post](https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/08/aggregate-all-the-things-qgis-expression-edition/) to aggregate with expressions. Could that achieve what you need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `Symbology > Stroke Width > Data defined override`, please try an expression:

```
sum("GIS@BUS_5_Min", group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))/100
```

Comment: @Kazuhito Does this expression work only if the geometries exactly match? For instance if one segment was longer than another that overlapped it for a short distance.

Comment: @GabrielC. Yes, you are right. If there is difference in any part of the geometry, this expression fails to match them.